# Winforms Designer Support for Inherited Custom User Controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

**Background**

I've got two custom user controls:

- `CustomUserControl1`: Initially created as a basic class file that inherits from `UserControl`, has some designer added controls, and some properties/methods.
- `CustomUserControl2`: Initially created as a basic class file that inherits from CustomUserControl1. No further aspects developed currently.

**Question**

For the controls that show up in the designer in `CustomUserControl1`, is it possible to get those inherited controls to show up in the designer for `CustomUserControl2`? While `CustomUserControl2` has a UserControl icon in the solution explorer, when I double click it to bring up the designer, I just get a blank design surface. I would have thought that the controls inherited from `CustomUserControl1` would have shown up, but they don't.

Comment: It's the default behavior of visual inheritance. You have the option of enabling design mode using a custom designer and calling [`EnableDesignMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.enabledesignmode(v=vs.110).aspx). Also by setting controls [`Modifiers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233630(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `Protected` or `Public` you can let the controls properties be modified through the property grid.

Comment: In general I don't recommend using visual inheritance when you want to make essential changes in layout of inherited control.

Comment: so its unvisual studio than in stead of visual studio. I had same problems with the "visual ?? designer". When you come from an IDE that does this without problems (Delphi) it takes some while to adjust. Honest I like the language but I feel the IDE is a real downgrade. They should finally start improving this at microsoft.